# Cutting SVG Path in half vertically and get the result paths

Tags: javascript, svg, drawing, snap.svg

I'm trying to loop thru a SVG Font glyphs and each got it "d" property like:

```xml
<glyph glyph-name="A" unicode="A" horiz-adv-x="1366"
                   d="M-3 0l563 1466h209l600 -1466h-221l-171 444h-613l-161 -444h-206zM420 602h497l-153 406q-70 185 -104 304q-28 -141 -79 -280z"/>
```

After extracting the path which draws this letter **A**, I'm having a hard time finding a way to calculate a new path string which will cut the drawing by half (vertically).

[snapsvg.io](http://snapsvg.io/) seems to have the best api to perform this transformation, I tried to read thru the docs but its very advanced.

There's also [this](https://github.com/fontello/svgpath) library which lets you operate at a low-level, but it seems not useful in this case.

**Question:** Given an svgPath, how can I cut it by half and **obtain the 2 paths** representing the **2 sides** of the shape?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just clip it in half with a clipPath?

Comment: I'm trying to redraw a font's svg programmatically and I'm afraid clipPath is not usable, just "d" which is the path..

Comment: And you can't clip it programatically. Graphics engines have a clipping capability, that's how renderers implement clipping.